# regular expression to represent files under folder

Tags: regex

I have some txt files put under directory like below:

```
school_1/121/class.txt
school_1/200/classxyz.txt
...
```

So, there is always a folder under `school_1` named with a random number. Text files are put under the number folder.

In general, I need to use regular expression to represent all files under school_1/ folder. Is it correct to use the following ?

```
school_1\/.\/.*
```

What about `school_1\/.*` is it also fine?

Comment: `school_1\/.\/.* ` does not match your strings - see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/eT6tX1/1). `school_1\/.*` works. That is the difference.

Comment: why the first one doesn't work? What is the wrong part?

Comment: Because it requires 1 character after the first `/` and then a `/`. But you may have `121`, `200` after the first `/` - so the first one is not good. What are your criteria for a "valid" match? Anything after `school_1/`? Even just `school_1/`? Then why asking a question - you could check the regexps at the online regex testers

Comment: `*` is a quantifier which says that there could be any amount of `.` (which is any character), although I think in this case `+` is more correct, which means 1 or more -- based on you saying *I need to use regular expression to represent all files under `school_1/` folder.*

Comment: Note that asking *Is it correct to use the following* makes no sense if you do not provide exact requirements.

Comment: Try `school_1\/\d+\/.*`

Comment: @Kamehameha: Yes, it will also match those paths, but it will no longer match `school_1/`.

Comment: `school_1\/(?:\d+\/.*|.*)` ?